# Upgrading Oracle from 11.2.0.1 to 11.2.0.2 Patch Set

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g

I'm hoping to get some advice from Oracle linux experts on how best to perform this upgrade.

We have a development Oracle Linux box running Oracle 11.2.0.1.  On one of our queries we're getting a `ORA-07445 - exception encounterd: core dump [kkoiqb()+9581] [SIGSEGV] ... Address not mapped to object`.

After looking into it, I believe this issue is fixed in 11.2.0.2.  I've read lots about patching etc, but thinking there must be a straightforward method of updating/applying these fixes (that I cannot find)

It's Oracle Linux Server 6.1
Kernel Linux 2.6.32-100.34.1

Any advice appreciated

Sam

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to upgrade to a new patchset, why not go to the very latest patchset (11.2.0.4)?

In my opinion, you should go to the latest patchset, 11.2.0.4.0, and then the latest PSU, which I think is 11.2.0.4.4.

The reason is, the next time you run into a bug, if you open an SR w/ Oracle, the first thing they will ask, is to upgrade to the latest version.  Not to mention, there will be thousands of additional bug fixes between 11.2.0.2 and 11.2.0.4.

As far as doing the upgrade itself a few points:

1.)  Upgrade to a patchset entails installing a new ORACLE_HOME.  When you run the installer, it will guide you to do an upgrade of the DB.

2.)  If you're running on ASM, you'll need to upgrade the GRID_HOME first.  Grid Infrastructure must be greater than or equal to the DB version.

3.)  When you download the patchset, read the README file.  It will contain late breaking updates, and things to look for.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have a specific standalone patch number that solves the issue, then you may try to go with that. More likely, there will be a bundle patch (e.g. 11.2.0.1.21) that covers the issue along with lots of other patches.

Lastly, if the options above are not available, then you are left with the patchset 11.2.0.2. The application of bundle patches and patch sets are very similar. There is not other straightforward way of doing it that I know off. You might as well practise this in Dev and get your system up to the latest patchset available for 11.2.